# how to automate mobile app having different activity name like ola app

Tags: selenium, appium-android

Trying to automate app which is having different activity name on each and every page..like ola app..i have application which is having unique package name but different activity name on each page, how to pass activity name and package name while automate.. i mean how to get unique activity name..

Comment: One way would be to loop over all the elements and verify attribute values to differentiate between elements that share the same name and have no unique identifier.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter?  Use BDD such as Cucumber or JBehave?